# Compare two worksheets and update the master list with new data using ID number as the key

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, compare, match

I have two worksheets in the same workbook. One would be the master data ("Player Directory") and the other is a weekly summary page ("Player Tracking").

The Player Tracking page will have updated information and also new players that should be added to the Player Directory page.

I thought about creating 3 arrays. One for Player Tracking another for Player Directory and the last one for New information but I have been unsuccessful at getting anything to work and searching the internet.

What would be the best way to compare these two sheets and add the missing data to the Player Directory. Both sheets list the players by player ID so that would be a great place to start.

The information to be compared and updated is as follows using the Player Tracking Page:

1. If Player ID number is not found in the Player Directory then add this player to the Directory.
2. If the number is matched, compare Columns C and D and update the Player Name and Nicknames respectively in column C and D on the Player Directory Sheet and update any changes.
3. If the number is matched, add the Fee in column G from the Player Tracking worksheet to the fee number in column K of the and return the result of that new number in the column.

Player Tracking Worksheet (updated weekly)
[image]

Player Directory Worksheet (Master)
[image]

```
Sub DirectoryAdds()
    Dim arUpdates() As Variant
    Dim arOriginal() As Variant
    Dim arAdds() As Variant
    Dim wsPD As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Set wsPD = Worksheets("Player Directory")
    
    ReDim Preserve arUpdates(4 To ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
    ReDim Preserve arOriginal(4 To wsPD.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
    ReDim Preserve arAdds(4 To UBound(arUpdates, 1))
    
    'arUpdates = ActiveSheet.Range("B4", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
    'arOriginal = wsPD.Range("B4", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
        For i = LBound(arUpdates) To UBound(arUpdates)
            arUpdates(i) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2)
        Next i
        For j = LBound(arOriginal) To UBound(arOriginal)
            arOriginal(j) = wsPD.Cells(j, 2)
        Next j
    
        For k = LBound(arUpdates) To UBound(arUpdates)
            If IsError(Application.Match(arUpdates(i), arOriginal(j), 0)) Then
                k = k + 1
                arAdds(k, 2) = arUpdates(i, 2)
            End If
        Next k
    
    'Range("K2").Resize(j) = Application.Transpose(v3)
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update Worksheet

Adjust the constants and the two first arrays as you see fit.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DirectoryAdds()

    Const tgtName As String = "Player Directory"
    Const srcFirstRow As Long = 4
    Const tgtFirstRow As Long = 4

    Dim srcColumns As Variant: srcColumns = Array(2, 3, 4, 7)
    Dim tgtColumns As Variant: tgtColumns = Array(2, 3, 4, 11)

    Dim PT As Worksheet: Set PT = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Dim PD As Worksheet: Set PD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtName)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Source As Variant, Target As Variant
    Dim NewRow As Long
    Dim Curr As Long
    Dim UB As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim k As Long

    If PT Is PD Then MsgBox "Wrong sheet selected.": GoTo exitProcedure
    Set rng = PT.Columns(srcColumns(0)).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo exitProcedure
    If rng.Row < srcFirstRow Then GoTo exitProcedure
    Source = PT.Range(PT.Cells(srcFirstRow, srcColumns(0)), rng)

    Set rng = PD.Columns(tgtColumns(0)).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
    If rng Is Nothing Then GoTo exitProcedure
    If rng.Row < tgtFirstRow Then GoTo exitProcedure
    Target = PD.Range(PD.Cells(tgtFirstRow, tgtColumns(0)), rng)
    NewRow = rng.Row + 1

    UB = UBound(srcColumns)
    For i = 1 To UBound(Source)
        On Error Resume Next
        Curr = WorksheetFunction.Match(Source(i, 1), Target, 0)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            On Error GoTo 0
            GoSub updateExistingRecord
        Else
            On Error GoTo 0
            GoSub addNewRecord
        End If
    Next

    MsgBox "Operation finished successfully."

    GoTo exitProcedure

updateExistingRecord:
    Set rng = PD.Cells(Curr + tgtFirstRow - 1, tgtColumns(UB))
    rng.Value = rng.Value + PT.Cells(i + srcFirstRow - 1, srcColumns(UB)).Value
Return

addNewRecord:
    For k = 0 To UB - 1
        PD.Cells(NewRow, tgtColumns(k)).Value = _
          PT.Cells(i + srcFirstRow - 1, srcColumns(k)).Value
    Next k
    Set rng = PD.Cells(NewRow, tgtColumns(UB))
    rng.Value = rng.Value + PT.Cells(i + srcFirstRow - 1, srcColumns(UB)).Value
    NewRow = NewRow + 1
Return

exitProcedure:
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow! I am extremely impressed. Thank you so very much it works perfect. What would the modification be to add a row when a new record is added to the Directory? I formatted the sheet for an extra 3 rows just to allow room to add rows for new entries just to make sure that the format is the same.Thanks again this was a huge help.